# Google Contacts Carddav Url

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to sync my google contacts into roundcube. I already installed 2 plugins (calendar sync with caldav is working like a charm with url, user and password) but I cant find the correct url for the carddav service.

Does anyone knows it?

Thank you
Moritz

Answer (score 7):

The URL at this moment is:

> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/YOUR@gmail.com/lists/default
> ```

But the client you're trying to connect from should not be using this permanently, but instead discover the correct URL by sending a `PROPFIND` to `https://www.googleapis.com/.well-known/carddav` as described in the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/#connecting_to_googles_carddav_server).

Anyway, Roundcube would have to support OAuth2 authentication, not user and password, to be able to connect properly, which I don't believe it does.

Comment: While it asks for a login, this URL returns a 404 Not Found (at this date and time) with Thunderbird and SoGO Connector.

Comment: It should not ask for login and password, but display an OAuth2 authentication screen, where you can login with your Google credentials and allow the app to use your data. It should not even ask for the URL, but fetch it automatically.

Comment: Well, when using `https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/YOUR@gmail.com/lists/default` (with my correct email) in Thunderbird for CardDAV with the [SOgo Connector](http://www.sogo.nu/downloads/frontends.html), I get a username/password prompt. I see this also with CardDAV for DavMail. In Firefox when I access this URL, I get a 404 Not Found. I do not believe that it works. I also get a 404 for `https://www.googleapis.com/.well-known/carddav`.